# Laravel 9 419 Unknown Status on sending POST request

Tags: laravel

Good day, I'm having trouble on sending post data to my Laravel project, It always shows Page Expired (419) on this,
[Error 419 on POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdXS3.png)

Here's the things I have done before coming up to my question:

1. Added `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=FALSE` on .env
2. Changed the config/session.php from `'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),` to `'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),`
3. Added ob_start(); at the beginning of public/index.php like this `<?php ob_start(); use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel; use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

This is my route

```
Route::post('/data', [AdminController::class, 'getSensorData']);
```

Also in I'm sending the data to the database from the post request using the controller.
The request works fine when the method is GET.
[200ok on GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCmFr.png)

Edit: It's working now, the fix was from @Ahmed Hassan. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this issue occur because you didn't send the CSRF token with the request

just add `@csrf` inside your form and it will work

also, you can exclude your URL in the `$except` list in the `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

I hope it's helpful

Comment: Hi, there's no form when I'm sending post data, also I'm getting the post data using the controller and will be sent to the database.

Comment: @Arcturus you can exclude your URL to `$except`  list in the `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` file,  check this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: Ahmed Hassan thank you for your comment, It works now in localhost, Ill try again in webhosting. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried installing barryvddh/laravel-debugbar a debuging tool so you can view the error behind it?

If yes show me the error on the console